Why is NSD Discovery not working in Oppo device?
I'm currently trying to use the NSD Discovery to discover services. I have write the code using the official documentation but my Nsd Discovery is not discovering any services on Oppo device.
This is my code for the Nsd Discovery and Nsd Service.
class NsdDiscovery(private val context: Context) {

    private var mHostAddress: InetAddress? = null
    private var mHostPort = 0
    private lateinit var mNsdManager: NsdManager
    private var isDiscovering = false
    private var mRandom = 0
    private val mDiscoveryListener = DiscoveryListener()

    fun updateConnectionListener(str: String, i: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "updateConnectionListener: $str $i")
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(
            Intent(BroadcastActions.DEVICE_CONNECTED.toString())
                .putExtra(Constants.IP_ADDRESS.name, str)
                .putExtra(Constants.PORT.name, i)
        )
    }

    inner class DiscoveryListener : NsdManager.DiscoveryListener {

        override fun onDiscoveryStarted(serviceType: String?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDiscoveryStarted: ")
            serviceType?.let {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDiscoveryStarted: $it")
            }
        }

        override fun onServiceFound(serviceInfo: NsdServiceInfo?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceFound: $serviceInfo")
            serviceInfo?.let { info ->
                Log.d(TAG, "onServiceFound: service info $info")
                if (info.serviceType.equals(SERVICE_TYPE)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onServiceFound: service type matches")
                    if (info.serviceName.equals(SERVICE_NAME)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceFound: Listening Same Machine")
                        return
                    }
                    mNsdManager.resolveService(info, MyResolveListener())
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        inner class MyResolveListener : NsdManager.ResolveListener {
            override fun onResolveFailed(serviceInfo: NsdServiceInfo?, errorCode: Int) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResolveFailed: $errorCode")
                serviceInfo?.let {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResolveFailed: Listening service $it")
                }
            }

            override fun onServiceResolved(serviceInfo: NsdServiceInfo?) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onServiceResolved: $serviceInfo")
                serviceInfo?.let { nsdServiceInfo ->
                    if (nsdServiceInfo.serviceName.equals(mRandom.toString())) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceResolved: Service Matched: $mRandom")
                        if (nsdServiceInfo.serviceName.equals(SERVICE_NAME)) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceResolved: Listening Port $nsdServiceInfo")
                            return
                        }
                        var inetAddress: InetAddress? = null
                        try {
                            inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(nsdServiceInfo.host.hostAddress)
                        } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }
                        try {
                            inetAddress?.hostAddress
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }
                        mHostPort = nsdServiceInfo.port
                        mHostAddress = nsdServiceInfo.host
                        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceResolved: Listening Port: $mHostPort")
                        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceResolved: Listening IP: $mHostAddress")
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Obtained IP: \n $mHostAddress",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        if (mHostAddress is Inet6Address) {
                            stopDiscoveringServices()
                            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                                discoverServices(mRandom)
                            }, 3000)
                        }
                        try {
                            val localHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost()
                            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceResolved: ${localHost.hostAddress}")
                        } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }
                        if (mHostAddress!!.hostAddress!! == STATIC_IP || mHostAddress is Inet6Address) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceResolved: equals to static ip or ipv6")
                            return
                        }
                        updateConnectionListener(mHostAddress!!.hostAddress, nsdServiceInfo.port)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onServiceLost(serviceInfo: NsdServiceInfo?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceLost: $serviceInfo")
        }

        override fun onDiscoveryStopped(serviceType: String?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDiscoveryStopped: $serviceType")
        }

        override fun onStartDiscoveryFailed(serviceType: String?, errorCode: Int) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartDiscoveryFailed: $errorCode")
            stopDiscoveringServices()
        }

        override fun onStopDiscoveryFailed(serviceType: String?, errorCode: Int) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStopDiscoveryFailed: $errorCode")
            stopDiscoveringServices()
        }

    }

    fun discoverServices(i: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "discoverServices: $i")
        mRandom = i
        mNsdManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE) as NsdManager
        if (isDiscovering) {
            Log.d(TAG, "discoverServices: Already Discovering")
            return
        }
        isDiscovering = true
        mNsdManager.discoverServices(SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener)
        Log.d(TAG, "discoverServices: started discovering")
    }

    fun stopDiscoveringServices() {
        if (isDiscovering) {
            isDiscovering = false
            mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(mDiscoveryListener)
            Log.d(TAG, "stopDiscoveringServices: discovery stoped")
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "NsdDiscovery"
        private const val SERVICE_NAME = "Client Device"
        private const val SERVICE_TYPE = "_http._tcp."
        private const val STATIC_IP = "192.168.43.1"
    }
}

class NsdService(private val context: Context) {

    private lateinit var mNsdManager: NsdManager
    private var SERVICE_NAME = "Server device"
    private val SERVICE_TYPE = "_http._tcp."
    private var isServiceRegistered = false
    private var tryUnregister = 0
    private var mPort = 0
    private var mRandomName = SERVICE_NAME

    private var mRegistrationListener: RegistrationListener? = object : RegistrationListener {
        override fun onServiceRegistered(serviceInfo: NsdServiceInfo?) {
            isServiceRegistered = true
            serviceInfo?.let {
                SERVICE_NAME = serviceInfo.serviceName
                Log.d(TAG, "onServiceRegistered: Service Name: ${serviceInfo.serviceName}")
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
                    .sendBroadcast(Intent(BroadcastActions.SERVICE_REGISTERED.name))
            }
        }

        override fun onRegistrationFailed(serviceInfo: NsdServiceInfo?, errorCode: Int) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRegistrationFailed: ")
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                registerService(mPort, mRandomName)
            }, 2000)
        }

        override fun onServiceUnregistered(serviceInfo: NsdServiceInfo?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceUnregistered: ")
            serviceInfo?.let {
                Log.d(TAG, "onServiceUnregistered: ${serviceInfo.serviceName}")
            }
        }

        override fun onUnregistrationFailed(serviceInfo: NsdServiceInfo?, errorCode: Int) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onUnregistrationFailed: ")
            isServiceRegistered = true
            if (tryUnregister < 3) {
                unRegisterService()
                tryUnregister++
            }
        }
    }

    fun registerService(port: Int, random: String) {
        mNsdManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE) as NsdManager
        if (!isServiceRegistered) {
            mPort = port
            val nsdServiceInfo = NsdServiceInfo().apply {
                serviceName = random
                serviceType = SERVICE_TYPE
                setPort(port)
            }
            mNsdManager.registerService(nsdServiceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mRegistrationListener)
        }
    }

    fun unRegisterService() {
        if (isServiceRegistered) {
            if (mRegistrationListener != null) {
                mNsdManager.unregisterService(mRegistrationListener)
            }
            isServiceRegistered = false
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "NsdService"
    }
}

This code is working fine for other devices. The Oppo device that I'm currently using for testing is Android 14. Also Pixel with Android version 14 is also working fine. Other Chinese devices like Huawei with Android 9, Infinix with Android 11 also working fine. Only this Oppo device is not discovering service.
